# bundle.js not found [Webpack]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

[UPDATE] bundle.js was actually created in memory. The best way is to keep index.html and bundle.js (configured in webpack.config.js) in the same directory to avoid any issue.

I have been trying to render a simple html file with webpack but can't figure out why I'm getting a 404. I understand that bundle.js could not be found so I tried different paths but it didn't work, any ideas?

I would appreciate your help.
Thanks.

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')

const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html')

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index')
  })

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
[...]
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  [...]
  <body>
      <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Folder structure

[image]

Comment: how do you compile "./src/index.js"? you need use webpack bundler to compile frontend source

Comment: webpack takes as an entry index.js and literally put it in bundle.js but that's not the problem I guess, the problem is it can't find bundle.js when rendering

Answer (score 2):

You don't have specified a correct path to your `index` file. If you have it on a `src directory` the code will look like this:

```
entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index')
  ],
[...]
```

Otherwise if you have it on your `views directory,` them the code will be the following:

```
 entry: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'views/index')
      ],
    [...]
```

And in your html file is `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>`

---

**UPDATE**

Base on your code at github try changing the following lines

```
entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index')
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
  },
    output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist', // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
```

The problem consist in that you're missing the `path.resolve(...)` in both your `entry point` and your `devServer` specifically

Hope helps :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help but unfortunately it didn't work for me, now I got an error the website can't be reached

Comment: @MinhPham updated answer ... That way resolves your problem?

Comment: I still get those errors : GET http://localhost:3030/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3030/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: @MinhPham weird ... can you provide the entire code that you have on your webpack.config.js so I can check where the real problem is?

Comment: @MinhPham updated answer. Let me know if that solves your problem